# What's the difference between these params

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C++, and I'm learning Qt.

Consider this line:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
        ui->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue);
```

What I don't understand is why you pass the address of a static (is it static?) method valueChanged (`&QSlider::valueChanged`) instead of the current object method address `&ui->horizontalSlider->valueChanged`. Although I can use this second option that works too.

Comment: I believe this is a part of Qt's unique way of distributing asynchronous events around your application. You don't pass the object receiving the event, but rather the associated method. I'm guessing now, but I think the difference between the two is that Qt will do some extra work in the background to fetch that method call from the object you've provided.

Comment: Read about pointers to members. They are different from generic pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the address of the member function which should be called.
The member function is not static though, that means it needs an object to work on.

```
class MyClass
{
    void aFunction();
}
```

here `MyClass::aFunction` is a member function.

What the compiler creates is similar to this

```
class MyClass
{
    static void aFunction(MyClass *this);
}
```

So whenever you call `aFunction` like `my_instance.aFunction()` the `this` pointer will be handed over implicitly, so the call basically becomes `MyClass::aFunction(&my_instance)`.
As a result the address of `aFunction` is the same for every instance of `MyClass`.
Yet to execute `aFunction` you need an instance of `MyClass`.

This is why in your case you have to provide `connect` with both the instance `ui->horizontalSlider` as well the function to be called on it `&QSlider::valueChanged`.

What I described is an oversimplification so take it with a grain of salt.
Moreover when you have virtual functions things change.